# magento does not create report file

Tags: magento, report

My Magento site that is consistently erroring out and giving me the report screen with the file name, but the file does not exist in the reports folder.
Also this folder have 777 permission.
what could be the cause of this issue.

Comment: Any log entries in Magento's logs or the web server error logs? There's not much to go on here. What error is given?

Answer (score 1):

Check permissions for the "var/cache" folder, it should be writeable to the system user running PHP. If yours is an Apache/mod_php installation, the user should be the same as in your Apache config (see User configuration directive).
Check the following folders:

- var
- var/log
- var/report
- var/cache

Just to test this, make sure all files and folders in Magento's "var" are accessible for the PHP user.
On Linux, your can do this by running:

```
#> cd /path/to/your/magento/folder/
#> find ./var -type f -exec chmod 666 '{}' ';'
#> find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 '{}' ';'
```

Please note that 777 and 666 permissions are NOT recommended in production environment, as they represent a security threat. Please tune your permissions, for all Magento installation files and folders, in production environment.

Comment: Why do you recommend 777 and 666 if you say it is not secure?!

Comment: Because I can't recommend better permissions that would work, unless I know the user/group under which PHP runs, and the user/group the files belong to.

Comment: Ideally, this should be:

    cd /path/to/your/magento/folder/; find ./var -type f -exec chmod 644 '{}' ';' find ./var -type d -exec chmod 755 '{}' ';'

but that would only work if the PHP user is the same as the owner of the files/folders

Comment: You could even set more restrictive permissions, such as 555 (folders) and 444 (files), limited to those sub-folders and files that don't need to be writeable by Magento itself (usually not the case of the "var" folder, as that is meant to be writeable by the application)